# convert text file to shapefile with python

Tags: python, shapefile, txt

I have a txt file that contains 5 columns(ID number,city,latitude,longitude,altitude) with tab delimiters. I want to convert this txt file into a shapefile format with python.
I am a beginner in python and i do not know how to do this. Can anyone help me?

Thanks in advance

Comment: what should be the output?

Comment: The output must be a shapefile that contains points that represent the location of each city. The attributes of each city must be also contained in the shapefile.

Answer (score 1):

There is a library to do this :

```
pip install pyshp
```

the import statement:

```
import shapefile
```

Now read your text file with something like:

```
w = shapefile.Writer(shapefile.POINT) #shapefile writer
filepath = 'yourfile.txt' #path to your text file
Lines[]=open(filepath).readlines() # read all the lines of your file
i=0 #index to help us get the headers
for line in Lines: 
   if i==0:
       i+=1
       for j in range len(line.split(";")):
           w.field('field{0}'.format(j)) #get the headers and stock them as fields
   
    w.point(line.split(";")[2],line.split(";")[3],line.split(";")[4]) #create points from last three columns
    w.record(field0=line.split(";")[0],field1=line.split(";")[1]) #add the fields you want to record in the file

w.save('outputshapefile') #write to a shapefile
```

Disclaimer! code not tested just to give you an idea, you can find more documentation [Here](https://github.com/GeospatialPython/pyshp#adding-records)